# Посчитать количество массива учитывая аргумент 'show' (bool : 1 / 0)

Tags: php

Нужно посчитать количество массива учитывая аргумент 'show' (bool: true/false).
Наглядный пример

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [acf_fc_layout] => box-main
        [title] => 
        [menu] => 
        [show] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [acf_fc_layout] => box-help
        [title] => 
        [menu] => 
        [show] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [acf_fc_layout] => box-system
        [title] => 
        [menu] => 
        [show] => 1
    )
```

Делаю с помощью:

```
count($array);
```

но считает весь массив без учета аргумента.

Достич такого результата:

```
    $countNavMenu = 0;
        foreach (get_field('sections') as $item) {
            if ($item['show'])
                $countNavMenu++;
        }

echo $countNavMenu;
```

Цель: скорость

Comment: Отфильтруйте массив с вашим аргументом, и используйте `count()`

Comment: массив такой приходит, а переделывать его, это тоже лишняя затрата. Хотелось бы узнать более оптимизованный способ

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает ваш подсчет через цикл?

Comment: Никакая скорость тут не нужна.

Comment: Да, понял что скорость для такой малой программы не нужна. Может в скорости и выиграешь доли секунд, но на фронте ощущаемого эффекта не увидишь. По-этому если стремиться за скорость, то только для большого скрипта. Можно использоваться мой пример в вопросе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

маловероятно. что какие либо прочие (кроме вашего цикла) варианты подсчета суммы будут более эффективны с точки зрения производительности и скорости. По крайней мере, чтобы замедлить скорость,  необходим очень большой объем данных. Но когда объем будет большой, пожалуй, все способы из перечисленных ниже (кроме `reduce`) приведут к увеличению расхода памяти.

Отфильтруйте и посчитайте

```
$filtered = array_filter($items, function($v){ return $['show']; });
$result = count($filtered);
```

либо сразу посчитайте, коли булево значение.

```
$result = array_reduce($items, function($res, $v){ return $res + $v['show'];}, 0);
```

или возьмите все значения `show`, отфильтруйте и посчитайте

```
$result = count(array_filter(array_column($items, 'show')));
```

впрочем, можно и не фильтровать

```
$result = array_sum(array_column($items, 'show'));
```

и так далее.

Comment: Проверил на скорость все ваши примеры. `array_sum` отработал быстрее всего. Цикл из вопроса на втором месте .

Comment: @user3265030 и сколько наносекунд там разница на 1000 прогонов?

Comment: на 10к элементов массива и 1к прогонов - 0,1 секунды разницы. С увеличением кол-ва элементов, `array_sum` начинает проигрывать. При 100к элементов и 1к прогонов - 0.4 секунды в пользу цикла.

Comment: ого, такой обширный и доходчивый ответ получил. Спасибо! Ответили в полностью развёрнутом виде.

Comment: @ВиталийБриль тогда галку у ответа ткните :)