# Поиск значения внутри масссива

Tags: php

Коллеги, добрый день. Я недавно занимаюсь разработкой на php и столкнулся с подобной проблемой. Если есть ответ на подобный вопрос, то перенаправьте, ибо я не смог "нагуглить" правильно.
Есть такой массив:

```php
count: 91
items:  
     1: 
      id: 515
      from_id: 12345
      date: 1509427858
      text: "Здравствуйте"

profiles:   
        1:  
         id: 12345
         first_name: "Ivan"
         last_name: "Ivanov"

groups  […]
```

Каким образом в данном массиве можно получить данные из полей first_name и last_name по полю id в массиве profiles, используя поле from_id массива items?

Проще говоря, у меня есть значение from_id, по этому значению я хочу получить first_name и last_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

наиболее эффективным с точки зрения производительности в любом случае будет обычный цикл, т.к. его можно прервать при выполнении условия. Прочие варианты всегда будут перебирать массив целиком, либо выделять доп. память.

Можно `id` в массиве сделать ключами, и просто обратиться к элементу с нужным ключом, это, наверное, наиболее понятный для чтения вариант кода

```
$id = ...
$profiles = array_column($data['profiles'], null, 'id');
$profile = $profiles[$id];
```

Comment: *наиболее эффективным с точки зрения производительности в любом случае будет обычный цикл* - это теоретическое предположение или какие-то замеры делали? Функции-то по идее написаны на С и не интерпретируются?

Comment: ну а цикл на пхп интерпретируется единожды, ему же не надо каждую итерацию заново интрепретировать, да и то если байт-код кешрован, то и не интрепретируются вовсе. Тут ключевой вопрос в том, что соответствие может быть найдено вообще в первом элементе и последующие итерации не нужны вовсе. При этом никаких встроенные функции для массивов не умеют прерывать обработку. Но даже если в цикле придется обработать все итерации, то вот недавно комментатор засекал время выполнения - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1035646/223826

Comment: Это *соответствие может быть найдено вообще в первом элементе* я понимаю. А про время интересно, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Можно натравить array_filter, он выберет только нужный элемент массива

```
$res = array_filter($array['profiles'], 
              function ($x) use($from_id) { return $x['id'] == $from_id; });
echo "{$res[0]['first_name']} {$res[0]['last_name']}";
```

Comment: `$res[0]['firstname']` только

Comment: а чего там смотреть то? `array_filter` возвращает массив элементов подходящих под условие, а не один элемент.

Comment: не разглядел на телефоне [0] :), подумал, что только первое значение выводится